# How to access to an entity instance in a subform?

Tags: forms, symfony4

## Summary

I want to access to an entity instance (of Media) inside a form related to an entity "Media" which is related to a form related to an entity "Project". How can I access to this entity instance ?

## What i have tried

I already found on the net that some people talked about an event callback like this :

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
    /** @var YourEntity $data */
    $data = $event->getData();
});
```

But that is only interesting when we had clicked on a 'add' button.
I want my entity on the first display of the page to show my image so that the user can see it and edit it if he wants to.

After, the user can add other images but it is another thing.

I also found some persons that say to put 'allow_add' to false, but it is not solving my problem.

## The code

Here is my two forms.
The form `Project` :

```
class Project extends AbstractForm
{
    use ArticleForm;
    use StatusForm;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('medias', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => Media::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ])
            ->add(
                'teaser',
                TextareaType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'label.teaser',
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'public',
                CheckboxType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'label.public',
                ]
            );

        $this->builderAddTitleAndBody($builder);
        $this->builderAddStatus($builder, $options['data']);
        $this->builderAddSave($builder);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => \App\Entity\Project::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the form `Media` :

```
class Media extends AbstractForm
{
    use EntityForm;

    public $formName = 'media';

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'file',
                FileType::class,
                [
                    'data'     => $this->entityFileInit($builder->getData(), 'file'),
                    'label' => 'label.picture',
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data_class' => null
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'alt',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'label.alt',
                    'mapped' => false
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => \App\Entity\Media::class,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

## Expected and actual results

I want Symfony to come at least to the template but Symfony tells me that $builder->getData() returns 'null'

Comment: Not sure about what you want to but if you want to access to data in subform there is two way to achieve this. First you pass data as option of your `Media` class in entry options and you add your custom keys in the defaults of the resolver. Or you use symfony form events `PRE_SET_DATA` or `POST_SET_DATA` but you have to declare it on the `Media` class.

Comment: Finally, i completely change the way i managed the whole thing. Thanks anyway for your answer.